# Tilting videos while not leaving black bars

Tags: premiere, editing

I have a video where the character is looking towards the left of the screen. I want to rotate the video in such a way so that the character looks towards the right side while not changing any proportion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mirror a composition?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13433/how-to-mirror-a-composition)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your video is in a Sequence.
Go to the Effects tab, and select Horizontal flip. 
Drag the Horizontal Flip effect onto your video clip in the timeline.
[image]